# Reset password link in authentitcation laravel 5.3.15

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

Please, I have problem with generating authentiication using laravel 5.3.15 command: `php artisan make:auth`
everything works unless when i click the button "Send Password Reset Link" I receive this error:

```
ErrorException in StreamBuffer.php line 95:
stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

here is the .env file information about email:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=******@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD='*** **** **'
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Thank you

Comment: Hi Essen, you find any solution? I face same issue if you find any solution please share with me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I solved it:

- go to `private function _establishSocketConnection` in file `<project-path>/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php`
- just after line `$options = array();` add following lines:

  `$options['ssl']['verify_peer'] = FALSE;`

  `$options['ssl']['verify_peer_name'] = FALSE;`
- save the file and restart the web server. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `app/config/email.php`

`smtp to mail`

Comment: Thanks for your help, you are talking about the MAIL_DRIVER, it is setted in .ev and i tried what you told m. the same erro:

Comment: Try adding following lines in the function 

`$options['ssl']['verify_peer'] = FALSE;`
 `$options['ssl']['verify_peer_name'] = FALSE;`

before this line : 

`$this->_stream = @stream_socket_client`

Comment: If you pardon me, in which file, I shoud add them ?

Comment: My Bad, forgot to mention that.. in the same file.. find the function `private function _establishSocketConnection`

Comment: there is no fuction in email.php called private function _establishSocketConnection

Comment: in the file StreamBuffer.php

Comment: I get the same Error

Answer (score 0):

The problem is there with the environment and not the code.
If you are working on local environment and want to test your app then I would suggest using

```
Either set MAIL_DRIVER=mailtrap in .env file
or 
change config directly in
<app>/config/mail.php
driver=>"mailtrap"
```

you can get the credentials here http://mailtrap.io for testing purpose.
When you move to live set mail driver to mail or smtp